# Passing data to the view through the constructor method in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently using the codeigniter tank_auth, at the start of every controller method I have to do the following:

```
$data['profile'] = $this->tank_auth->get_profile();
```

The main reason I do this is to display the current logged in username, and also get their privilege level.

I am going over the code trying to go by the DRY principle and have moved a lot of repeated code over to the _constructor method (Like checking if the user is logged in). I am just wondering if there is a way to move this code from the start of every method to the constructor.

My current constructor method looks like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // If the user isn't logged in redirect to login page.
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
        redirect('auth/login');

  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add variable `$data` to the controller and use it for all your view data. For example:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['profile'] = $this->tank_auth->get_profile();
}
```

When calling the view remember to call it like this:

```
$this->load->view('my_view', $this->data);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, if I do it this way how would I pass data to the view from the controller ?

Comment: Thats in the second code snippet: `$this->load->view('my_view', $this->data);
`

Comment: Thanks thats it! Although I needed to change all other vars from $output['title'] = "Bla bla"; to $this->output['title'] = "Bla bla";

Comment: Indeed. It is a big change but it helps keeping the code DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend CI_Controller with MY_Controller and put the login check in the constructor of MY_Controller. Just extend all controllers which need this check from MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller.